# Show app icon on contact details in Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm trying to add my app icon in contact details, to work like a shortcut, i manage to show a title and subtitle but the app icon doesn't appear and i don't understand how to show him and how to add the event to navigate to an specific page after click in the custom cell.
someone can help me?

i have the following code on my contact manager:

```
public static void addContact(Context context, MyContact contact) { 
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    // add condition that you want to check

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            Integer.parseInt(contact.id));
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.LABEL, "Title");
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM);
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL,
            "Title");

    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, "Transferência");

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
            .withValues(contentValues).build());

    try {
        resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String ex = e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

`

and the following service on android manifest

```
 <service
        android:name="com.[appPackage].SyncService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE" android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
    </service>
```

someone can help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, each `RawContact` on the `Contacts` DB was synced by a particular app, so if that's not already the case for you, I would suggest you have your app insert its own `RawContacts`, and not mangle with `RawContacts` existing on the device, as they can be deleted, edited, reset by the controlling app at any time.

Now to get your app's "*actions*" displayed on the native contacts app, you need to declare your contacts custom `mimetype` and related fields, you do this with a special xml file called `contacts.xml` that you declare in your manifest which maps different `DataKinds` to Data columns like DATA1, DATA2, etc.

You then need to have an activity to catch the intent that will be fired when the user clicks on your custom row.
You declare the intent in the contacts.xml file as well, and you then need to set a similar `intent-filter` in your activity's manifest block so Android will know which activity to launch.

Here's official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#CustomData & here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStreamDataKind

Here's a tutorial: https://medium.com/@stephen.cty/android-account-sync-adapter-and-contacts-contract-database-983281be4847

Again, try to make sure that the `myRawContactId` value in that tutorial is pointing to a RawContact your app had created, that will prevent future bugs with Google messing with your custom data rows